# Tabela com class table-striped não muda a cor da linha

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, table

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando alterar a cor de uma linha em uma tabela com a class table-striped (zebrada), porém parece que a regra da table-striped sobrepõe minha regra:
**tr class="{{$p->quantidade <= 1 ? 'bg-danger' : ''}}"** como podem ver no código abaixo:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <td class="bg-primary"><strong>Nome</strong></td>
    <td class="bg-primary"><strong>Valor</strong></td>
    <td class="bg-primary"><strong>Descrição</strong></td>
    <td class="bg-primary"><strong>Qtde</strong></td>
    <td class="bg-primary"><strong>Tamanho</strong></td>
    <td class="bg-primary"><strong></strong></td>
    <td class="bg-primary"><strong></strong></td>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($produtos as $p)        
    <tr class="{{$p->quantidade <= 1 ? 'bg-danger' : ''}}">
        <td>{{ $p->nome }}</td>
        <td>{{ $p->valor }}</td>
        <td>{{ $p->descricao }}</td>
        <td>{{ $p->quantidade }}</td>
        <td>{{ $p->tamanho }}</td>
        <td>
            <a type="submit" href="/produtos/mostra/{{$p->id}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a type="submit" href="/produtos/remove/{{$p->id}}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

O problema é que minha tabela fica com as linhas vermelhas somente em colunas pares, quando é uma coluna ímpar a linha não está ficando vermelha. Mas se eu remover a class table-striped minha regra funciona, alguém pode me ajudar com esse erro? 
Imagem da tabela com erro: https://ibb.co/SVSy006
Imagem da tabela sem erro: https://ibb.co/z6LcsqL

Comment: Olá amigo tente forçar o css troque 'bg-danger' coloque 'bg-danger !important'

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, tentei aqui mas sem sucesso, eu já vi alguns problemas parecidos em outros projetos pedindo ajuda aqui no StackOverFlow, eles forçam dentro do arquivo css parece para que a table striped não sobreponha as cores, acho que tenho que colocar algo parecido lá como .table { bg-danger !important} // Mas esse tipo de código não parece ser reconhecido pelo css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O bootstrap define a linha ímpar com o código:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #f9f9f9; }
```

então para sobrepor esta definição você deve seguir a mesma hierarquia na declaração da linha bg-danger:

```css
.table-striped>tbody>tr.bg-danger:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color:red; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>nome</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Anna</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Debbie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='bg-danger '>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>John</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação amigo!

Comment: @LincolnBiancardi de nada. Mais 2 dicas: por [orientação do stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) não devemos usar os comentários para socializar/agradecer... se a solução for boa você pode (além de votar a favor) marcar a resposta como "aceita" (check verde)